# point DNS data for more than one domain

Tags: web, dns

My DNS data looks like the following, for all the domains I have.  I need to point one of them to this directory on mywebsite: var/newdomain/  as the following data points to var/www

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN SOA ns1.first-ns.de. postmaster.robot.first-ns.de. (
    2011042200   ; serial
    14400        ; refresh
    1800         ; retry
    604800       ; expire
    86400 )      ; minimum

@                        IN NS      robotns3.second-ns.com.
@                        IN NS      robotns2.second-ns.de.
@                        IN NS      ns1.first-ns.de.

@                        IN A       40.4.111.77
localhost                IN A       127.0.0.1
mail                     IN A       40.4.111.77
www                      IN A       40.4.111.77
ftp                      IN CNAME   www
imap                     IN CNAME   www
loopback                 IN CNAME   localhost
pop                      IN CNAME   www
relay                    IN CNAME   www
smtp                     IN CNAME   www
@                        IN MX 10   mail
```

Answer (score 0):

Hosting a second domain on the same server involves setting up virtual hosts on the web server.

If you need to create an IP-based virtual host and assign a second unique IP address to the network adapter that is hosting the first web site.  The DNS change simply means you add a new A record for the new IP address.  For example:

```
newdomain IN A 40.4.111.78
```

If getting a second unique IP address is not what you are looking for then your web server will have to use a name-based virtual host.  This involves setting up a new CNAME record.

```
newdomain IN CNAME www
```

The question seems to imply that the DNS somehow directs the web user to the hosted /var/newdomain directory, but it does not.  The web server must be configured to do that.  The DNS name only gives the web server some information to go on in order to decide which area it should serve.

If the underlying question is how to host a second domain on a web server, that should be asked directly.